# Is there a RoboGuice linter?

Tags: java, android, roboguice

I'm using RoboGuice as the dependency injection framework for a new Android app.  Although it has some niceties, if I misconfigure something, it's possible to get an exception at runtime (notably null pointer or RoboGuice config exceptions).

Is there a way to automatically lint or vet RoboGuice?  A way to catch if I forgot something in the Application's module, for example.